# whats syntax for calling other scenario in same feature file?

Tags: karate

I know we can call one scenario into other with syntax

```
* def ret = call read('fileName.feature@scenarioName')
```

This is fine, but if i wish to call other scenario from same feature file, it doesn't makes sense to pass file name. I would like some relative path like feature to avoid maintenance if someone renames file.

So my question - is it possible to call other scenario in same feature file without mentioning feature file name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is absolutely not possible. Also, this will confuse the hell out of people trying to read your test-suite in the future.

Note that you can use variables ([fixed in 0.9.6.RC1](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1082))

```
* def common = 'common.feature'
* def ret = call read(common + '@scenarioName')
```